# subset data frame without specifying columns for plotting

Tags: r, plot, subset

Is it possible to subset a data frame without specifying columns? I keep getting the error message "undefined columns selected". I don't want to specify the column as I am trying to generate a plot where the size of each point is:

```
1 - (a value associated with the data point)
```

The annoying thing is that the actual value I'm trying to get is located in a separate file (not in the plotting data). So, in other words, if I am plotting X vs Y, for each point (X,Y), there is an associated value (say Z) in a different file that I can locate based on sharing identical row.names().
What I have so far (which doesn't work) is this:

```
cex.val <- 1 - mutsig[row.names(dataall)]
plot(dataall, col="red", pch=16, cex=cex.val)
```

mutsig and dataall are my data frames. It fails each time as it is requesting for a specified column. Of course it will work if I do:

```
cex.val <- 1 - mutsig[row.names(dataall[1,])]
```

But then I'm only subsetting one specific entry, and every point size will be based off that one entry. I'd like to be able to plot every point with its own cex value based specifically on what mutsig subsets off the row name of the dataall point being plotted

Comment: could you provide an example replicable ?

Comment: this error usually happens when one forgets to use a comma when subsetting a `data.frame`, for instance when you try `df[some_row_condition]` instead of `df[some_row_condition,]`. In your case, try `mutsig[row.names(dataall),]`

Comment: ^ that actually worked!! I was so obsessed with trying to work on the dataall data frame I didn't even remember to check the other data frame....